# Attempt to redefine node compilation error in JAGS

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I am trying to run the following JAGS code from R. I am just showing some part of the code where the error is occurring.

```
for(mmm in 1 : p){ 
                 for(jj in 1 : K){
                  vv[jj] ~ dbeta(1,1);
                 }
        pp[1] <- vv[1];
                 for (jjj in 2 : K){
                          pp[jjj] <- vv[jjj] * (1 - vv[jjj-1]) * pp[jjj-1]/vv[jjj-1];
                 }
    }
```

The error is `Attempt to redefine node vv[1]` on line 3. I am not sure why the error is occuring. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this `1:K` loop nested within your `1:p` loop. So when `mmm` goes from `1` to `2` you are overwriting the values in `vv`. Without knowing more about the model there are two possible solutions.

1. Remove these from the nested for loop.
2. Index the values you have inside of the `1:p` loop by `mmm`.

Assuming that the second answer is what you need it would look something like this:

```
for(mmm in 1 : p){ 
  for(jj in 1 : K){
    vv[mmm, jj] ~ dbeta(1,1);
  }
  pp[mmm,1] <- vv[mmm,1];
  for (jjj in 2 : K){
    pp[mmm,jjj] <- vv[mmm,jjj] * 
    (1 - vv[mmm,jjj-1]) * pp[mmm,jjj-1]/vv[mmm,jjj-1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and yes I am looking for the second answer.